# Curl login with hash or random hidden codes

Tags: php, curl

I'm trying to login to a site and from there i want to send a message with the form available there. It looks like

```
<form method="POST" action="pm.php">
    To: <input type="text" name="user" />
    <input type="hidden" name="pm_tid" value="ef0gjpmgwag5g21agjg" />
    <input type="hidden" name="box" value="new" />
    Subject: <input type="text" name="subject" />
    message:  <textarea name="text"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" value="Send" />
</form>
```

I managed to enter the login and to the page where is the `message send form` but in that html code you can see that there is a hidden random hash value which changes after every reload. I want to get that correctly and post in the form. Only then my message will be sent. Please don't say that it's IMPOSSIBLE. It is possible. One of my classmate succeeded in it but he is not helping me.
Please try to help me.

Comment: This is most likely to aid against [CSRF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery) and you shouldn't attempt to circumvent it like you are doing.

Comment: Get the form (with CURL), use preg_match_all() to grab the hidden fields and fill your post with the name/values, then post your form. NB this will not circumvent javascript adding or altering the values

Comment: @FDL — Using cURL wouldn't be circumventing CSRF protection. CSRF protection is there to stop Mal from tricking Alice into making a request to Bob, not to stop Mal making the request herself.

Comment: But i'm doing that for educational purpose. I just used in that site to send message to me itself. I'm trying to learn it for any future needs. I heard `preg_match_all` can help. And i did but after i get the hash and submit it again in other `curl_exec` it might have changed.

Comment: It's not impossible - it's trivial - which begs the question - what have you tried?

Answer (score 2):

This looks like CSRF protection. The usual implementation for this is to store the token in a cookie (or server session if a session token cookie is used) and then compare it to the token in the form.

You need to:

1. request the HTML document containing the form
2. store the cookies you get at the same time (assuming that they come with the form)
3. [parse the html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-to-parse-and-process-html-with-php) to get the token from the input
4. make the request to `pm.php` including the token and the cookie

Comment: Can u please give me the entire code? I'm totally new to curl and stackoverflow

Comment: No, I'm not going to write your application for you.

Comment: Ok then, can you tell me how does it works? I mean, first we visit using curl to the form. Then we use `preg_match_all` to get the hash. Then again we visit curl to the form and use the hash value there. But the hash could have changed right?

Comment: [Wikipedia explains](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery#Prevention). Yes. No, read the link in step three. No, you visit `pm.php`. No, you send the cookie data back so the server associates you with the previous token.